# how to find bunch of files and archive them in one line of bash

Tags: linux, bash

let's say I'd like to find all the files with suffix .wzd under the current directory and archive all the files founded at a time, how can I do it?

the following doesn't work, by the way

```
find . -name "*.wzd" 2>/dev/null -exec tar -cvf wzd.tar {} \;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `-print0` with `find` to output null-delimited filenames, and pipe to `tar` using `-T - --null` to read null-delimited filenames from stdin.

```
find ... -print0 | tar ... -T - --null
```

Answer (score 2):

backticks would work too:

```
tar -cvf wzd.tar `find . name "*.wzd" -printf "%f "`
```

Answer (score 0):

> `-exec command {} +`

This variant of the `-exec` action runs the specified command on the selected files, but the command line is built by appending each selected file name at the end; the total number of invocations of the command will be much less than the number of matched files.  The command line is built in much the same way that `xargs` builds its command lines.  Only one instance of `'{}'` is allowed within the command.  The command is executed in the starting directory.